# Want to send automatic mails from email server, That To addres has to read from email that i received.?

Tags: linux, powershell, shell-script, smtp, administration

I want to send multiple mail automatically.

I will receive mail as

**FROM:** abc@domain1.com

**TO:** 123@domain2.com

**BODY:** mail contains (username@domain3.com)

- What I want to is take the username@domain3.com from the mail body.
- And write new mail for the TO:username@domain.com with some mail looks like this for example:

**FROM:** 123@domain2.com

**TO:** username@domain3.com

**Subject:** Some things.

- Is it possible to do this by using a mail server or are there any other ways to do it.
- When ever a mail receoves from abc@domain1.com it has send the mail automatically like above? Is ispossible to do by some script or any ways?

Please help me on this.

Comment: Is it possible or not guys.?

Comment: It is most definitely possible. On linux there is an application called `procmail` which you can use to pass variables to a shell script. You would pass the `from address` to the script and have the script send the email.